# Expression for loading more work on someone who is already busy

Tags: expressions, idioms

I'm looking for something you'd say to a co-worker when you're asking him/her for help, even though he/she is already super busy.

Something like:

> "I don't mean to _____ , but ...".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a friend in Texas who referred to this as "packing the burro"—but he also referred to his (then-) wife as "burro." Not recommended.

Comment: And yet I sense the potential for an expression involving “camel” and “straw”.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the word **overburden**.

From Collins (via [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/overburden)), the verb form means:

> to load with excessive weight, work, etc

You would use it as:

> I don't mean to **overburden** you, but...

Or, if you definitely don't want to exaggerate, you could simply use **burden**, which simply means "to load with" as in:

> I don't want to **burden** you

Burden can also be a noun, so you might also say "I don't want to add to your burden but...". A burden is something that is carried or a load, however it can also be used to mean a lot of work pending (work*load*). For example, a long "to do" list is a heavy mental burden.

You could even use it to refer to yourself as in "I don't want to be a burden, but...", meaning you yourself are adding to the mental workload. Of course, if solving the problem together means that you are able to help with the workload, then you are acting to unburden your colleague.

Comment: Along the same lines, "overload" also works.

Comment: Hi @NicolasSamuel. You're welcome and welcome to ELU! I'd advise you to leave this a "while" (a day or so) to see if you get other answers and let people vote on the answers if they're going to, then make your own choice. You get rep for accepting an answer. Word requests are usually quite popular here.

Answer (score 2):

As in:

> "I don't mean **to tax** you, but"...

**tax**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tax)

> use to the limit;  burdensome or excessive demand; a **strain**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most common word here would be **bother**:

> I don't mean to **bother** you.

---

At first I only left this as a comment because I felt the question was too subjective. Then I realized I could use the Google Books NGram Viewer to at least indicate something objective.

In doing so, I had to formulate something slightly different. Rather than being able to query for "don't mean to * you" I had to query for "sorry to * you," but I feel that those two phrases are close enough.

Interestingly, I had to add to that wildcard search *bother*, *tax*, and *overburden*.

But here are [the results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20to%20*%20you%2Csorry%20to%20bother%20you%2Csorry%20to%20tax%20you%2Csorry%20to%20overburden%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Csorry%20to%20%2A%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20see%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20tell%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20hear%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20inform%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20find%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20trouble%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20disturb%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20lose%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20leave%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorry%20to%20have%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorry%20to%20bother%20you%3B%2Cc0):

[image: sorry to x you]

According to Google, neither *tax* nor *overburden* appear often enough to be charted. While *bother* is the most common.

After *bother*, it shows **disturb** and **trouble**.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the expression "***pile something on(to) somebody***" using the phrasal verb "***pile on***".

> "I don't mean to ***pile more work on you***, but could you do this for me?".

Oxford Learner's Dictionary:

> **[pile something on(to) somebody](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pile-on)**
>   to give somebody a lot of something to do, carry, etc.
>   He felt his boss was piling too much
>   work on him.